# Compute a conditional probability of normal random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Suppose $X, T$ are continuous random variables, and $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$, $T$ have density function $f_T$. (But $X,T$ do not have joint density)

Is there any way to compute the following conditional CDF? 
$$
P(X \le A(T) \ | \ T= t)
$$
where $A(T)$ is a function with variable $T$.

---

I was trying to rewrite above conditional CDF by using definition
$$
P(X \le A(T) \ | \ T=t) = \frac{P( \{X \le A(T)\} \cap \{ T=t \})}{P(T=t)}= \frac{P(X \le A(t))}{P(T=t)}
$$
but $P(T=t) =0$, and so the above formula is undefined and thus this approach failed.

---

Any comments or suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, $P(X\lt A(T)\mid T)=B(T)$, where, for every bounded measurable function $C$,
$$
E(C(T)\,\mathbf 1_{X\lt A(T)})=E(C(T)B(T)).
$$
With no further indication on the joint distribution of $(X,T)$, it is difficult to go further. If $(X,T)$ was independent, then
$$
E(C(T)\,\mathbf 1_{X\lt A(T)})=E(C(T)\Phi(A(T))),
$$
where $\Phi$ is the standard normal CDF, hence, unsurprisingly,
$$
B=\Phi\circ A.
$$
But you say this is not the case... At another extreme, if $T=X$ with full probability, then
$$
B(t)=\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}1&\text{if}&A(t)\gt t,\\0&\text{if}&A(t)\leqslant t.\end{array}\right.
$$